# How to send back the data got from response.on('end') to the client-side

Tags: node.js

I'm new to NodeJs and I'm having the problem with response.on('end') I still can't find out the method to send the data I got from the response to the client side.

```
  exports.getCheckoutSession = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
  const https = require('https');
  const tour = await Tour.findById(req.params.tourId);
  console.log(tour);
  //parameters send to MoMo get get payUrl
  var endpoint = 'https://test-payment.momo.vn/gw_payment/transactionProcessor';
  var hostname = 'https://test-payment.momo.vn';
  var path = '/gw_payment/transactionProcessor';
  var partnerCode = 'MOMO';
  var accessKey = 'accessKey';
  var serectkey = 'secretKey';
  var orderInfo = 'pay with MoMo';
  var returnUrl = 'https://momo.vn/return';
  var notifyurl = 'https://callback.url/notify';
  var amount = (tour.price * 23000).toString();
  console.log(amount);
  var orderId = req.params.tourId;
  var requestId = req.params.tourId;
  var requestType = 'captureMoMoWallet';
  var extraData = 'merchantName=;merchantId='; //pass empty value if your merchant does not have stores else merchantName=[storeName]; merchantId=[storeId] to identify a transaction map with a physical store

  //before sign HMAC SHA256 with format
  //partnerCode=$partnerCode&accessKey=$accessKey&requestId=$requestId&amount=$amount&orderId=$oderId&orderInfo=$orderInfo&returnUrl=$returnUrl&notifyUrl=$notifyUrl&extraData=$extraData
  var rawSignature =
    'partnerCode=' +
    partnerCode +
    '&accessKey=' +
    accessKey +
    '&requestId=' +
    requestId +
    '&amount=' +
    amount +
    '&orderId=' +
    orderId +
    '&orderInfo=' +
    orderInfo +
    '&returnUrl=' +
    returnUrl +
    '&notifyUrl=' +
    notifyurl +
    '&extraData=' +
    extraData;
  //puts raw signature
  console.log('--------------------RAW SIGNATURE----------------');
  console.log(rawSignature);
  //signature
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  var signature = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', serectkey)
    .update(rawSignature)
    .digest('hex');
  console.log('--------------------SIGNATURE----------------');
  console.log(signature);

  //json object send to MoMo endpoint
  var body = JSON.stringify({
    partnerCode: partnerCode,
    accessKey: accessKey,
    requestId: requestId,
    amount: amount,
    orderId: orderId,
    orderInfo: orderInfo,
    returnUrl: returnUrl,
    notifyUrl: notifyurl,
    extraData: extraData,
    requestType: requestType,
    signature: signature
  });
  //Create the HTTPS objects
  var options = {
    hostname: 'test-payment.momo.vn',
    port: 443,
    path: '/gw_payment/transactionProcessor',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)
    }
  };

  //Send the request and get the response
  console.log('Sending....');
  var req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`Status: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`Headers: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
    console.log('Type of body', JSON.stringify(res.body));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let fullBody = '';
    res.on('data', body => {
      fullBody += body;
      console.log(' Real Body');
      console.log(fullBody);
      //console.log('Type of body', body.payUrl);

      // console.log(JSON.parse(body).payUrl);
      // res.redirect(JSON.parse(body).payUrl);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      const payURL = JSON.parse(fullBody).payUrl;
      console.log('payUrl', payURL);
      console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
  });

  req.on('error', e => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
  });

  // write data to request body
  req.write(body);
  req.end();
});
```

This is the url I got from response

```
payUrl https://test-payment.momo.vn/gw_payment/payment/qr?partnerCode=MOMO&accessKey=F8BBA842ECF85&requestId=5f38cc86954a6206211e2842&amount=23000&orderId=5f38cc86954a6206211e2842&signature=37ae247d56efd9ed6630b7d7d1435b88ffb8895956da5711a62ebbab8118aa7b&requestType=captureMoMoWallet
```

Can you please tell how could i send the data from res.on('end'), the "payURL" in the picture above, to client-side. I have tried some methods like res.writeHead, res.send, res.json( ) .... But they all returned error: res.send, res.writeHead, res.json...  is not a function

This is my client-side, . If you guys don't mind , please also show me how to automatically redirect the payURL site above when the client click my button. Should I keep using window.location.replace like above ?

```
export const bookTour = async tourId => {
try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bookings/checkout-session/${tourId}`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: 'a=1'
      }
    ).then(res => window.location.replace(res.redirectURL));
    console.log('The res', res);
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err);
  }
};
```

This is my index.js

```
 if (bookBtn) {
  bookBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.textContent = 'Processing...';
    const tourId = e.target.dataset.tourId;
    bookTour(tourId);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're shadowing the `req/res`-variables from your `getCheckoutSession`-handler by using the same names for your http-request. If you change it to:

```
const request = https.request(options, response => {
    // ...
    let fullBody = '';
    response.on('data', body => {
      fullBody += body;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
      const payURL = JSON.parse(fullBody).payUrl;
      // access the handler "res" object here
      res.send(payURL);
      // alternatively use res.json({payURL}) to send a json response
    });
});
```

it should work fine.

Note: Nowadays you should definitely use `const/let` instead of `var` (see [this](https://blog.usejournal.com/awesome-javascript-no-more-var-working-title-999428999994) for more information)

Comment: Thank you so much man, Holy... I have been stuck with this problem for more than 3 days, read so many documents , tried different ways but still can't find out the reason. Today , I finally find it out. I can't sleep well in the last 3 days . 1000% thank for your help.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score -1):

Simple,

```
res.on('end', () => {
   const payURL = JSON.parse(fullBody).payUrl;
   res.json({
     payURL: payURL
   })
});
```

or other way

```
res.on('end', () => {
  const payURL = JSON.parse(fullBody).payUrl;
  res.status(200).send({
    payURL: payURL
  });
});
```